# saving variables in line from file?

Tags: c, file, char, spaces

I'm trying to read lines and extract information from it. My text has for example;

```
abate   terminar, hacer cesar
abated  amainado, amplacado, mitigado
```

which is a dictionary. 
First word is english and rest are Spanish. I'm trying to save the english word into one variable and then the rest of the line into another one variable. I have no idea how to do that? I wrote this code that reads all the text file and prints it all.

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    char filename[] = "/Users/MyName/Desktop/span.rtf";
    FILE *file = fopen ( filename, "r" );

    if (file != NULL) {
        char line [1000];
        while(fgets(line,sizeof line,file)!= NULL) /* read a line from a file */ {
                fprintf(stdout,"%s",line);        }

        fclose(file);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Read about strings in your C textbook.

Comment: Use [getline](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Line-Input.html) function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a great start, using `fgets()` to read in whole lines which can then be parsed is a good approach in general.

Next you need to think about how to store your dictionary. One way might be a statically sized array of structures:

```
struct {
 char *english;
 char *spanish;
} words[1000];
```

This assumes no more than 1000 words.

To store each line, just find the first space character and let that be the split between English and Spanish:

```
size_t word_count = 0;
while(fgets(line, sizeof line, file) != NULL)
{
  char * const sp = strchr(line, ' ');
  if(sp != NULL)
  {
    *sp = '\0';
    while(isspace((unsigned char) *++sp))
      ;
    if(isalpha((unsigned char) *sp)
    {
      words[word_count].english = strdup(line);
      words[word_count++].spanish = strdup(sp);
    }
  }
}
```

Something like that should get you started. This assumes the existance of `strdup()`, if you don't have that re-implementing it is trivial. Of course you should add code to check for memory allocation failures.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
char english[256];
char spanish[256];

while(fscanf(file,"%[a-z]%*[ ]%[a-z, ]\n", english, spanish) != 0) {
    fprintf(stdout, "English: %s\n Spanish: %s\n", english, spanish);
}
```